# Python & pymysql: Database Table with hyphen in name

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, pymysql

I need to query data from a mysqldatabase with the table name containing hyphens.

```
current_table = "tw3-10_1"
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM " + str(current_table ) 
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

Unfortunately I get:
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-10_1' at line 1")

Is there any way to work around that issue? Unfortunately I cannot change the names of the tables.....

Comment: Perhaps quoting the table name in backticks `\`tw3-10_1\`` will help.

Answer (score 3):

You can normally use backticks to quote a table name or column name, in case it contains unhelpful characters.

```
current_table = "`tw3-10_1`"
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM " + current_table
```

or if you prefer

```
current_table = "tw3-10_1"
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `{}`".format(current_table)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried both methods, I do not get an error any more but somehow I jut get an empty tuple if I do afterwards: cursor.execute(sql2) and then current_data = cursor.fetchall(), If I change the table name to one without a hyphen I get the data

Answer (score 0):

try like this, I don't know about MariaDB but quotes should work in SQL

```
sql2 = """
    SELECT
            *
    FROM "{table_name}"
    """.format(
            table_name='table-with-hyphens'
        )
print(sql2)
    # SELECT
    #         *
    # FROM "table-with-hyphens"
```